# Architecture? Business logic separate from big data

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, architecture, bigdata

I have an application that relies on business logic to group IOT sensors. The business logic is a PostgreSQL database that keeps track of accounts, deployed devices, configurations, etc.

We all know that these IOT devices are capable of generating millions of data points a day. I don't think I should store "Big Data" inside PostgreSQL. Even if I did I might want to keep my results separate from the business logic.

I also have the need to run visualizations on the "Big Data". Right now I store the "Big Data" in AWS S3 as JSON blobs and visualize it with Athena and Quicksite.

So, two questions.

First, am I on the right track as far as Architecture? Separating business logic from "Big Data."

Second (assuming yes to first question), if my visualizations rely on some of that business logic how do I combine the two? Save meta data into the S3 bucked about the business logic that generated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing architecturally wrong with having two separate data stores for two different kinds of data.  I'd stop calling it "Business Logic" as it isn't logic, it's metadata.

Personally I'd wrap a service around the metadata so that it can be retrieved at processing time, that way you can maintain a single source of truth.  If that's challenging, your idea of exporting it to the S3 buckets would work as well, but then you have to worry about stale data & such.

Comment: Also, can you describe the service you would wrap about the meta data a little more? Like save unique ID's of the meta date into the "Big Data" and then retrieve when it's time to analyze? Thanks.

Comment: I assumed this would be easy, querying a JSON service, but it is not obvious how to integrate this into QuickSight...  It looks like leaving it in PostgreSQL is your best bet as you can then do joins in QuickSight to join your BigData with tables/views in PostgreSQL

Comment: Do not have much experience with Postgres. Recently faced a similar issue, I'll just share what I did. I made use of AWS EMR, which makes use of S3 buckets and comes it comes with Hive. This is one such architecture where using Hive allows for the use of internal and external tables. External tables is what will help you with the problem of separating the meta data, as the schemas for external tables is stored separately and it "points to the actual data". So it will not manipulate the actual data itself. Additionally, you can still make do with declarative queries like HiveQL.